# \midchapskip spacing in memoir chapter style

Tags: spacing, chapters, memoir, vskip

I am creating a custom chapter style using the memoir class. It is defined by the following:

```
\makechapterstyle{balloon}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\begin{center} \chapnamefont \chaptername}
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{\space}
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter \end{center}}
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par\vskip \midchapskip }
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont %
        \begin{center}%
            \MakeUppercase{##1}%
        \end{center}}
    \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\vskip \afterchapskip}%

    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Large}
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Large}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}%

    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-25pt}
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{10pt} % <-- Value in question.
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{7pt}
}
\chapterstyle{balloon}
......
\chapter{The End of a much-applauded Speech -- The Presentation of Dr. Samuel Ferguson -- Excelsior -- Full-length Portrait of the Doctor -- A Fatalist convinced -- A Dinner at the Travellers’ Club -- Several Toasts for the Occasion}
```

I realize some of the the declarations within `\makechapterstyle` are redundant, and they will be removed when I'm done working on the style.

The problem I'm facing is that changing the value of `\midchapskip` has inconsistent effects on the format of the heading. This value should control the spacing between the chapter text (e.g. "Chapter 1"), and the chapter title (e.g. "The End of a much-applauded Speech...").

Negative values of `\midchapskip` have no effect at all on the spacing, and positive values have sporadic effects. For example, there is a 10pt difference in the actual spacing when `\midchapskip` is set to 20pt and 10pt, but no actual difference between a value of 10pt and 0pt. Why is this and how can I accurately adjust this spacing?

TL;DR: Why isn't `\midchapskip` having the intended effect in my chapter style?

Answer (score 1):

You have used the `center` environment in your redefinition of `\printchaptertitle` --- use `\centering` instead. So, less any typos

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont%
  {\centering \MakeUppercase{##1} \par}}
```

The following shows the result of the change to `\printchaptertitle` together with `\setlength{\midchapskip}{-75pt}`, thus negative `\midchapskip` values do have an effect, just as any other value will.

[image]

Perhaps someone else can explain the difference in spacing of `\begin{center}` versus `\centering`.

**EDIT**

```
Here's an MWE with four different `\midchapskip` values to show their effects.

% balloonprob.tex  SE 598175
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makechapterstyle{balloon}{%
    \renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\begin{center} \chapnamefont \chaptername}
    \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{\space}
    \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter \end{center}}
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par\vskip \midchapskip }
    \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip \midchapskip }
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont %
%        \begin{center}%
%            \MakeUppercase{##1}%
%        \end{center}}
    {\centering
      \MakeUppercase{##1} \par}}
    \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\vskip \afterchapskip}%

    \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Large}
    \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Large}
    \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}%

    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-25pt}
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{20pt} % <-- The default
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{10pt} % <-- Value in question.
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{5pt} % <-- Value in question.
%    \setlength{\midchapskip}{50pt} % <-- Value in question.
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt} % <-- Value in question.
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{-75pt} % <-- Value in question.
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{7pt}
}
\chapterstyle{balloon}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{The End of a much-applauded Speech -- The Presentation of Dr. 
Samuel Ferguson -- Excelsior -- Full-length Portrait of the Doctor -- 
A Fatalist convinced -- A Dinner at the Travellers’ Club -- 
Several Toasts for the Occasion}

%\lipsum[1]
\setlength{\midchapskip}{-10pt}
\chapter{The End of a much-applauded Speech -- The Presentation of Dr. 
Samuel Ferguson -- Excelsior -- Full-length Portrait of the Doctor -- 
A Fatalist convinced -- A Dinner at the Travellers’ Club -- 
Several Toasts for the Occasion}

\setlength{\midchapskip}{0pt}
\chapter{The End of a much-applauded Speech -- The Presentation of Dr. 
Samuel Ferguson -- Excelsior -- Full-length Portrait of the Doctor -- 
A Fatalist convinced -- A Dinner at the Travellers’ Club -- 
Several Toasts for the Occasion}

\setlength{\midchapskip}{10pt}
\chapter{The End of a much-applauded Speech -- The Presentation of Dr. 
Samuel Ferguson -- Excelsior -- Full-length Portrait of the Doctor -- 
A Fatalist convinced -- A Dinner at the Travellers’ Club -- 
Several Toasts for the Occasion}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `centering` was helpful, and allows some negative values to work, but there is still no difference between values like -10pt, 0pt, and 10pt.

Comment: I tried three identical `\chapter` commands but put `\setlength{\midchapskip}{P}, where `P` was `-5pt`, `0pt` and `5pt`, before the `\chapter` so that the space between the chapter heading and the title text could be compared in one document. The spaces were different. Trying with `-10pt`, `0pt` and `10pt` produced bigger differences. I have no idea what you have done.